# SwiftUI: Execute code when back button for NavigationView is pressed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have MainView, which has a navigationLink to EditProfileView.

When I press the back button on EditProfileView, I want some code to execute that updates a database.

I would use onDisappear(), but the issue is that EditProfileView has another view ImagePickerView presented as a sheet come up, and having that view come up triggers onDisappear().

In other words, I want my database code to execute only when we press the back button to go from EditProfileView back to MainView.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your own back button to replace the native one as the left button. Then programmatically dismiss your view.

Comment: Use .onDisappear, if using NavigationView -> NavigationLink to detect event on press back button